# Fix license in old Git commits

Tags: git, github, git-rewrite-history

I have a currently private GitHub repository which exists for a few years now. In the `README.md` file there is a license, which is not accurate any more.

Now I would like to turn this private repo into a public one, with the fixed license. Anyway, all of the old commits still contain the old (wrong) license.

How could I solve this? My first idea was to [squash the repository to a single commit and destroy everything else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43853944/how-to-squash-a-git-repository-to-a-single-commit-and-destroy-everything-else/), but maybe there is a better way to achieve what I want.

As you can see from the other question, keeping history is not important, but OTOH it doesn't hurt as well.

What actually hurts is having old commits with the wrong license.

Any ideas?

PS: I want to ensure that nobody is able to get an old commit, not even if they know the commit's id. So, the solution to this must also pay attention to updating the remote repositories, such as GitHub.

Comment: You can use `git filter-branch` to do this but shouldn't the history reflect that the license was changed from that point in time? Or are you retroactively changing it for the whole project?

Comment: I'm proactively changing it for the entire project, and I don't want it to be publicly usable with the old license (even if this only applies to an old state of the source). I want the new license for everything, before I make things public.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim Does `git filter-branch` allow you to edit files in the history? I thought it was just to remove files instead. I think it sounds like your best bet is to squash the commits and start again.

Comment: Oh yes it does. Gimme a sec. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `filter-branch` to do this. First write a small script that rewrites the tree for a given commit. e.g., Following is something that changes `something` to `something else` in the `README.md` file only if it exists.

```
if [ -f README.md ]; then
    sed 's/something/something else/g' README.md > tmp
    mv tmp README.md
fi
```

Save this as `change.sh` and then run the following

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter "/bin/bash $(pwd)/change.sh" HEAD
```

This will rewrite all the commits going back from HEAD. If you've made a mistake, you can go back to the earlier tree using `git reset` and try again.